# <sizeof(T)> as inherited class template parameter in c++

Tags: c++

I've been trying to make a transition from a simple self-made game engine written in C to C++ and came across a nice book by Mike McShaffry (Game Coding Complete).
And for the love of bios almighty I cannot wrap my head around his 'optional template class', namely this piece of code:

```
class optional_empty { };

template <unsigned long size>
class optional_base
{
public:
     // some code here
};

template <class T>
class optional : public optional_base<sizeof(T)>
{
public:
     // some code here
};
```

Why is 'sizeof(T)' used as template parameter when inheriting, and not just plain 'T'?
Does it make it possible to have T's of dynamic size?
There is no 'sizeof...' operator, so it's probably not related to variadic templates.
Or is it?
Thanks.

Comment: `T` is a type. `sizeof(T)` is an integral constant, Have you look at [sizeof documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `optional_base` is not expecting a template *type parameter* but a template *value parameter* (of type `unsigned long`).

Comment: It's usually called a non-type parameter.

Comment: @T.C. I've checked in the Standard. Actually the expression *template value parameter* never occurs. But in TC++PL 4th edition it does several times (see §25.2.2 **Values as Arguments**). So, I'll not edit the answer but will upvote your comment!

Comment: Oh man, I should get more sleep, it's so simple - thank you, guys, thanks, Paolo!

Comment: @PaoloM You can call them any way you like; when they're though in a formal context, they are called non-type template parameters or arguments, since they're synonyms.